# How to resolve an "incorrect syntax near '=' " error in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm getting the following error in SSRS:

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
An error has occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for dataset 'Dataset1'.
incorrect syntax near '='
```

Before this error, I was getting an error that complained about parameter order(  " Must pass parameter number 3 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value', after the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed inthe form '@name = value' . ) .. and I fixed that by changing the order of parameters(basically I put begin/end dates after other parameters).

```
exec [dbo].[prc_RPT_Select_BI_Completes_Data_View_tst]

@AccountIDs  = NULL,
@ClientIDs  = NULL,
@SupplierIDs  = NULL,
@FromDate = '19001010',      
@ToDate = '19001110',
@CompleteType = NULL,
@SourceType = NULL,
@SurveyStatus = NULL,
@IsSupplierUser = NULL
```

[image]

How do I fix this problem? Would the fact that the stored-proc. has dynamic sql all throughout it affect this?

Also,when I run this in SSMS manually:

```
exec [dbo].[prc_RPT_Select_BI_Completes_Data_View_tst] '20121010', '20121011', null,null,null,null,null,null
```

then it works fine.  So it might have to do with SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original error did not complain about the order of parameters. It instead stated (a little cryptic) that you should not mix positional and named parameters when calling a procedure.

There are now two posible causes for the new error:

1. You have a typo in the calling statement.
2. You have a typo in the procedure itself.

Try to grab the exact statement that is send to the db and run it manually in SSMS. That should tell you more. I did notice that you used different parameter values in the two examples.

If you can't resolve it with that, run a SQL Server Profiler trace capturing stored procedure statement started and stored procedure statement completed as well as user error while running the report. In there you should be able to see the exact statement that caused the error.

Comment: when you said `You have a type in the calling statement.`  - did you mean "typo" ? thanks